# Vue "on-change" method not working with checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use a method with a checkbox and it's not firing in VueJS. I have included snippets from the template section and methods section of my component. The component and everything else in it load just fine without any console errors, but I can't get this method to fire when I click the checkbox. What am I doing wrong?

FROM template:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-on:change="myMethod(this)" />
```

FROM methods:

```
myMethod: function (chck) {
                        if (chck.checked == true) {
                            console.log("true");
                        } else if (chck.checked == false) {
                            console.log("false");
                        }
                },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing `this` to an event handler in Vue will pass the *entire component* into the event listener, instead of just the element. This is because, inside of vue-bindings, you're just writing JavaScript within the scope of the component.

Instead, don't pass anything in your template (which will result in your method being passed the regular `event` object), and use `event.target.checked` to check if the checkbox was checked (actually, don't do it *exactly* this way, this is just a more "direct" solution. See below for the *proper* way to do it).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    myMethod: function(event) {
      if (event.target.checked) console.log("checked");
      else console.log("unchecked");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" @change="myMethod" />
</div>
```

However, it's worth noting that the **proper** way to do this is with `v-model`. That way, you maintain a single source of truth, and your app remains data-driven:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tickBoxChecked: false,
  },
  methods: {
    myMethod: function() {
      if (this.tickBoxChecked) console.log("checked");
      else console.log("unchecked");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="tickBoxChecked" @change="myMethod" />
</div>
```